# Selenium web driver in PHP, Without installing pip

Tags: python, php, selenium

I am trying to use the Selenium web driver in PHP. So created a python script, And running that via shell_exec command.

When I am running the script it's showing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "login.py", line 2, in <module>
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

The problem is don't wants to install the selenium driver via pip, Because I want to use this code on a shared server, And on the shared server, we can't install anything.
So is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my code:-

**index.php**

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$command = escapeshellcmd('login.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

**login.py**

```
    import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

usernameStr = 'putYourUsernameHere'
passwordStr = 'putYourPasswordHere'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?'
             'service=mail&continue=https://mail.google'
             '.com/mail/#identifier'))

# fill in the username and hit the next button

username = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierId')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

nextButton = browser.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
nextButton.click()

# wait for transition then continue to fill items

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))

password.send_keys(passwordStr)

signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
signInButton.click()
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can use it in a shared server as well. You _have_ to install selenium for doing this.

Comment: But on shared server we can't install anything, So we needs to use require_once or include_once type thing in python. ( Sorry don't have any experience in python )

Comment: You don't need to install again and again! You only install once using pip!

Comment: If I install via pip on my local machine, then it will install it on local machine, And I think it will not create directory like vendor which we can upload on server, And use that.

Comment: Yes, But looking for something different. trying to auto-fill username and password here https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login , Above URL is just for demo.

Comment: Oh! I see. I am not entirely sure but I don't think Selenium can be used over a shared server. But like I said, I am not sure. Let someone else answer the question. Sorry I could not help you.

Comment: No problem, Thanks (y). You tried to help me. :)